# Cleanup after carpet spill

Tags: cleaning, carpet

I just spilled 14 ounces of an [energy drink](http://www.panix.com/~wotw/neuro.png) containing fructose and small amounts of fruit and vegetable juices on my (probably nylon) carpet.

I immediately covered the stain with about 50 ounces of salt, waited ten minutes, and vacuumed up the salt.  There is no visible stain, the entire area is either completely dry or just barely damp to the touch (I keep changing my mind), and there is no sign of any stickiness or other remaining evidence of the spill.

Question:  Am I done with the cleanup, or should I be worried about sugar or other ingredients staying in the carpet and doing ongoing damage, either directly by interacting with the carpet fiber or indirectly by attracting bugs or rodents or God knows what else?

Answer (score 1):

If you're still worried, alternate lightly dampening the area followed by blotting away the water with a colorfast absorbant cloth; that should delute and rinse away any remaining residue. But if you can't feal any residue after it dries, I'd duggest not worrying about it and trusting that it'll be dealt with next time you hit the area with carpet cleaner.